# Failed to execute goal on project XX Could not resolve dependencies for project. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-central

I am compiling my repo for maven project. I am getting some dependency errors. **I know the  maven central repository no longer supports insecure communication over plain HTTP and requires that all requests to the repository are encrypted over HTTPS.**. This is what I tried adding the following code in

> pom.xml

of my project:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central maven repo</id>
      <name>central maven repo https</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

and in the

> ../maven/conf/settings.xml

added the following:

```
<profile>
    <id>my profile</id>
        <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central maven repo</id>
                    <name>central maven repo https</name>
                    <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
                 </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile
```

But nothing seems to work, I get the same error. Somewhere I saw that i need to change settings.xml in m2 path

> ~/.m2/settings.xml

but in my path i find this:

```
~/.m2> ls
repository  wrapper
```

The error is as follows:

```
Failed to execute goal on project XXX: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:XXX:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:3.6.2 (compile), javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:4.0.0 (compile), org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.9 (compile), com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0 (compile), commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1 (compile), org.geotools:gt-geojson:jar:22.0 (compile), org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:22.0 (compile), org.geotools:gt-geojsondatastore:jar:20.2 (compile), com.xx:Demo:jar:1.0 (compile), javax:javaee-web-api:jar:7.0 (provided), org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.9 (compile), com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1 (compile), javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.11 (compile), com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11 (compile), com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11 (compile), javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.geotools:gt-geojson:jar:22.0: Could not transfer artifact org.geotools:gt-geojson:pom:22.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/geotools/gt-geojson/22.0/gt-geojson-22.0.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1]
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, the error still persists.

Comment: If you're using a recent version of Maven, you shouldn't need this. (btw, the id of the repository should be `central`). Most likely one of your dependencies has an explicit overwrite of the repository in its pom.

Comment: @RobertScholte you were right, it was with the ID. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem while working on a j-ee that runs on payara. To build your project, please ensure that you first stop your payara server first

Answer (score 0):

Because [`pom.xml` files themselves may contain `<repository>` elements](https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/websites/production/maven/content/pom.html#Repositories), it is entirely possible that a transitive dependency of yours is specifying a URL to a Maven repository that begins with `http`.  Tracking these down can be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid adding/updating repositories in thepom, see https://blog.sonatype.com/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/ for the details.

The preferred way to solve this is:

```
<settings>
  ...
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>central-https</id>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  ...
</settings>
```